# Simple RSync EXCLUDE option?

Tags: linux, rsync

I want a simple and working (multiple) `exclude` option inside my `rsync` command. Lets say i will exclude `a file` and `a directory`:

- /var/www/html/test.txt
- /var/www/html/images/

What i did is:

`rsync -avz --exclude="/var/www/html/test.txt" --exclude="/var/www/html/images/" /var/www/html root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/var/www`

or

`rsync -avz --exclude=/var/www/html/test.txt --exclude=/var/www/html/images/ /var/www/html root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/var/www`

or

`rsync -avz --exclude /var/www/html/test.txt --exclude /var/www/html/images/ /var/www/html root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/var/www`

..

But however, the `--exclude` is NOT WORKING!
Everything is going out!

- How to do it in this simple format please?

*Note: I also don't want to use external exclusion list file. Just want all in one simple command.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i got it solved by myself after i've learned and tested many times. The real problem was the understandable (for me) `--exclude` option usage format.

I don't know how others are doing but i just found out that:

- **"--exclude" path CAN NOT be the full absolute path!**

Because i was using the path(s) like: `--exclude /var/www/html/text.txt` which caused the thing DOES NOT work. So i used like:

```
--exclude text.txt --exclude images/
```

.. and it WORKS!

Comment: Just a warning:  this command will exclude `text.txt` files and `images` directories anywhere it finds them in the file hierarchy (i.e. not just at the top level of the directory being backed up), which might not be what you want.

Comment: I wish it worked like that but this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

I personnaly like the `--exclude={text.txt,images/}` format.

- Remember that with rsync, all exclude (or include) paths beginning with / are are anchored to the **root of transfer** which in your example will be the `/var/www/html` directory!!, so if you specify `/text.txt` it will be only the file which is @ the root of your transfer directory not above in the tree. You can find more infos and examples [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/)